# Convert code returned by bundleMDX into HTML string for RSS while using mdx-bundler

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, mdxjs

I want to convert code returned by `bundleMDX` to string for RSS reader I'm writing so I can use it with `ReactDOMServer.renderToStaticMarkup(mdx)` like:

https://github.com/tailwindlabs/blog.tailwindcss.com/blob/acb8dcfbc733e25c0e1f4e8af5323da421071cbc/scripts/build-rss.js#L36

The Tailwind Blog above uses `next-mdx-remote` where it works but I'm not sure how to do the similar thing in `mdx-bundler`.

I've tried wrapping code in `MDXLayoutRenderer` using `mdxSource`:

```
import { MDXProvider } from '@mdx-js/react'

export const MDXLayoutRenderer = ({ mdxSource, ...rest }: IMDXLayoutRenderer): JSX.Element => {
    const MDXLayout = React.useMemo(() => getMDXComponent(mdxSource), [mdxSource])

    return <MDXLayout components={MDXComponents as any} {...rest} />
}
.
.
.

const mdx = (
    <MDXProvider>
        <MDXLayoutRenderer mdxSource={code} />
    </MDXProvider>
)
```

But this throws weird TS errors like:

> 'MDXProvider' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MDXProvider'?ts(2749)

If I make `mdx` a function & return the value from it, then also it doesn't work:

```
const mdx = () => (
            <MDXProvider>
                <MDXLayoutRenderer mdxSource={code} />
            </MDXProvider>
        )
```

All I need is to pass a `html` formatted string so that I can send it to RSS package feed.

My example is exactly similar to the Tailwind Blog with 1 difference: I'm using `mdx-bundler` instead of `next-mdx-remote`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Could you provide a [mre]? The error mentions `MDXProvider` being used as a type, but no where does that happen in the code you provided.

Comment: @juliomalves sure I can. just added an edit to specify `MDXProvider`. creating a repro now :)

Comment: @juliomalves while making a repro, I found the answer. weird huh. was stuck on it for like 2-3 weeks. just posted it below :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oopsie while making a repro, I again got this error:

> 'MDXProvider' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof MDXProvider'?ts(2749)

This error is weird but as this file was small, I noticed the extension I had was `.ts` but I was using JSX in the `mdx` function.

So changed the extension to `.tsx` & it worked. Was stuck on this weird problem for like 2-3 weeks.